# codeigniter project not displaying foreign characters

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, utf-8

I just need some quick direction to figure this out.
In my Codeigniter project `$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';` is set properly as you can see.
My serbian letters contained in static data are displayed properly but ones that are pulled out of MySql is replaced by `?` marks.
What else should I look for to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your database/table has the right `utf8_general_ci`? [collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-database.html) set, more info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-applications.html)